# Converting User Input into a usable function

Tags: vue.js, keyup

This is all done in Vue.Js

I don't know if the title is appropriate however, the end of goal of what ***I'm trying to do is to have the user submit an input that I can put inside a QR Code***.

Here's How I tried:

1. Create a keyup.enter event in the new input text tag.

   ```html
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Website Name" keyup.enter="newqrurl">
   ```
2. Create new data, newUrl and set it equal it to " "

   ```js
   data() {
     return {
       newUrl: ""
     }
   },
   ```
3. In the new function created newqrurl() I added the new data newUrl, and set it equal to = to ""

   ```js
   methods: {
     newqrurl() {
       this.newUrl = " "
     }
   ```
4. Now i want to insert the new function into my string.

   ```html
   <img src="https://www.qrtag.net/api/qr_transparent_12.png?url='newUrl'" alt="qrtag">
   ```

I may make no sense, since I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Did you want the text entered into the `<input>` to go anywhere? Is that meant to be stored in `newUrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!

- You should use `v-model` to bind the value of your text input to the data variable.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Website Name" v-model="newUrl">
```

- Now you can use a **computed property** to calculate the QR code image source

```js
computed: {
  qrImage () {
    return `https://www.qrtag.net/api/qr_transparent_12.png?url=${this.newUrl}`
  }
}
```

- And finally, change the `src` attribute of your `img` element to reference your computed property.

```html
<img :src="qrImage" alt="qrtag">
```

Note the `:` before the `src` attribute.

In the end it might look something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Website Name" v-model="newUrl">
    <img :src="qrImage" alt="qrtag">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        newUrl: ""
      }
    },

    computed: {
      qrImage () {
        return `https://www.qrtag.net/api/qr_transparent_12.png?url=${this.newUrl}`
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'd lose `v-model` and go with `@keypress.enter="newUrl = $event.target.value"` to fit better with OP's original event handler. If you use `v-model`, this will make a new image request for each letter typed